# Removing console.log throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app which is built using reactjs and react-mdl. There is a tab show info, episodes, and cast. When episode is clicked John, Jane in header should be changed to other text and so 55 episodes plus other content that is beneath the tab. The code that i coded works what i want but i think its not the proper way and there is a bug. I know its my fault but dont know how could i solve it.

```
class MovieDetailView extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movie:[ ],
      activeTab:1
    }
  }

  render(){
    console.log("Tab ID: ", this.state.activeTab);
    let movie = this.state.movie;
    const mainCastJoin = _.join(movie.mainCast, ', ');
    if(!this.state.movie){
      return(
        <p>Loading</p>
      );
    }

    else{
      return(
        <div className="demo-big-content">
          <Layout fixedHeader fixedTabs>
              <Header>
                {this.state.activeTab >= 0 ? <HeaderComponent movie={this.state.movie} activeTab={this.state.activeTab}/> : ' '}
                  <HeaderTabs ripple activeTab={this.state.activeTab} onChange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })}>
                      <Tab>SHOW INFO</Tab>
                      <Tab>EPISODES</Tab>
                      <Tab>CAST</Tab>
                  </HeaderTabs>
                    <Link to="/"><i className="material-icons arrow_back">arrow_back</i></Link>
              </Header>
              <Content>
                  <div className="page-content">{this.state.activeTab >=0 ? <MovieInfo movie={this.state.movie} activeTab={this.state.activeTab} /> : ''}</div>
              </Content>
            </Layout>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default MovieDetailView;
```

**HeaderComponent.js**

```
const HeaderComponent = ({activeTab, movie}) => {
  const mainCastJoin = _.join(movie.mainCast, ', ');
  const renderHeader =
    console.log('kk');
    if(activeTab === 0){
      return(
        <div>
          <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
            <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;{mainCastJoin}
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
          </HeaderRow>
        </div>
      );
    }

    if(activeTab === 1){
      return(
        <div>
          <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
            <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;episode
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
          </HeaderRow>
        </div>
      )
    }

    if(activeTab === 2){
      return(
        <div>
          <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
            <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;main cast
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
          </HeaderRow>
        </div>
      )
    }

  return(
    <div>{renderHeader}</div>
  )
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

This code works but if i remove console.log then i get an error

```
Error in ./src/component/HeaderComponent.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (10:4)

      const renderHeader =
       // console.log('kk');
      if(activeTab === 0){
          ^
         return(
           <div>
             <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
```

How can i solve this? Why is it causing an error? What is the efficient way to solve such problem?

**UPDATE**

```
let renderHeader =  () => ({
   return(
    if(activeTab === 0){
      return(
        <div>
          <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
            <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;{mainCastJoin}
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
          </HeaderRow>
        </div>
      );
    }

    if(activeTab === 1){
      return(
        <div>
          <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
            <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;episode
          </HeaderRow>
          <HeaderRow>
            <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
          </HeaderRow>
        </div>
      )
    })
}
```

Rectifying the above code does not yield any output. It rather gives new error{this.renderHeader()}

```
const renderHeader =  () => ({
     if(activeTab === 0){
     ^
              return(
              <div>
              <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
```

Comment: WTH is the `const renderHeader =` doing there anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have something after an assignment operator (`=`) that can be assigned to the variable (or constant in this case).

In the working code, you are assigning the return value of `console.log()`.

In the broken code, you've attempted to put an `if` statement there.

Comment: @Learner — Your updated question is a *new* question. It shouldn't be an edit to the existing one.

Comment: sorry for not knowing that. But now the problem is solved with the help of @Tushant i now keep this in my mind. Thanks for your help too. Like Tushant has said he need expert thought on his solution, can you please help on his answer so i can learn it too.

Answer (score 3):

5 expert had already stated the cause of an error in your code with good explanation. Now you are into another trouble which you can overcome with my solution. But i am a learner too. I am sharing this solution for myself to learn from those experts. If i were to solve this problem, my solution would be

```
const ShowInfoHeader = (movie, mainCastJoin) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
        <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
      </HeaderRow>
      <HeaderRow>
        <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;{mainCastJoin}
      </HeaderRow>
      <HeaderRow>
        <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
      </HeaderRow>
    </div>
  );
}

const EpisodeHeader = (movie) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <HeaderRow title={movie.title}>
        <IconButton name="more_vert" id="demo-menu-lower-left" />
      </HeaderRow>
      <HeaderRow>
        <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>&nbsp;episode
      </HeaderRow>
      <HeaderRow>
        <i className="material-icons">history</i>&nbsp;55 episodes/ 4 seasons/ 2013 -
      </HeaderRow>
    </div>
  );
}


const HeaderComponent = ({activeTab, movie}) => {
  const mainCastJoin = _.join(movie.mainCast, ', ');

  if(activeTab===0){
  return(
    <div>{ShowInfoHeader(movie, mainCastJoin)}</div>
  )
}
if(activeTab===1){
  return(
    <div>{EpisodeHeader(movie)}</div>
  )
}
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

I would appreciate expert thought on this solution if it is the good way of dealing such problem or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want  a variable to contain the result of an if, you have to wrap it into an IIFE (immediatly invoked function expression):

```
var renderHeader=(function(){
if(sth){
return "value";
}
return "standard";
})();
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
var renderHeader=" null";
if(sth){
renderHeader="sth is true";
}
```

Comment: If I rectify my mistake, does the code looks efficient?

Comment: @Learner: im more a js than a react guy. Ask someone who is better at that. Quentin for example

Answer (score 0):

you have not assigned a value to renderHeader!
works with console uncommented beacuse you assign the result of `console.log` on it.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting const renderHeader = to console.log(). Which is allowed(its not useful but allowed).

But when you remove that, you are setting "const renderHeader =" to if statement. Parser can't parse that and your JavaScript is breaking.